Infinite scroll pagination with browser back button
I have infinite scroll feature to load more data.
So when user scroll towards the bottom of the page, below code updates the URL like:

/in/top-wear.html?page=2
/in/top-wear.html?page=3
.
.
.
and so on.

But the problem is that if user presses the browser back button then it leaves
the page /top-wear.html instead of going back to previous page like ?page=3 ?page=2 ?page=1 etc.
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(" top", categoryLoading);
        const handleScroll = () => {
            if(categoryLoading) return;
            const sumOfInnerHeightAndScrollY = (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY);
            const offsetHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
            const scrollBottomPercentage = ((offsetHeight-sumOfInnerHeightAndScrollY)/offsetHeight)*100;

            if (scrollBottomPercentage < 25) {
                const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const currentPage = parseInt(searchParams.get('page') || 1);
                const nextPage = currentPage + 1;

                console.log(" scroll bottom", paginationButton);

                searchParams.set('page', nextPage);

               
                
                history.push({ search: searchParams.toString() }); //"page=2 and so on..."
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, [history, categoryLoading]);    
    

I am NOT able to find what's the problem.
Please help here.
Note:
I just want that if user is currently in page=4 and now user pressed the browser back button, then it should go to page=3 and so on...

history back button functionality is not working properly, because re-render component many times for infinite scroll functionlity, please check the component rendering

@UmeshSingh, I have already added categoryLoading validation. If API is already running then it will not go further.

and, in Firefox browser, it is working fine.

Using hooks for Chrome browser (Browser suport hooks) automation typically involves utilizing libraries like Puppeteer or Playwright in a Node.js environment. These libraries allow for programmatic control of the Chrome browser to perform tasks such as navigating pages, clicking elements, and scraping data
I looking this for nextjs application maybe short this issue

I debug the code and found one solution, I have added a custom button having click function window.history.back(). Now I just want that whenever user presses the browser back button, then it should click that button programmatically.
